# How to any exclude any specific folder from karate execution

Tags: karate

I have created multiple folders under the feature folder in my karate project but I want to run all feature files except feature file in one or two specific folder. How we can achieve this from command line from maven command or any other solution?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is use tags (recommended) or you can pass multiple folders as the last part of your command, e.g. `some/dir1 some/dir2`.